# How are devinstall and devuninstall scripts being used?

Tags: npm, npm-scripts, husky, git-husky

I am trying to reuse husky for other projects (not just config file), building a lib of sorts that will be used by all other projects.
I cannot understand how and when devinstall and devuninstall scripts are executed. Cannot find any documentation either on npmjs.com.
Can someone help understand when this are getting executed please?

Comment: Both scripts appear to be executed in their CI tests as they are defined/run in both `.travis.yml` and `appveyor.yml`. See [here](https://github.com/typicode/husky/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=%22npm+run+devinstall%22%2C+%22npm+run+devuninstall%22&type=)

Comment: In that case how does it call the `_install` script during `npm install` that adds the git hooks?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've been trying to understand that too.
Turns out they do something at publication time that renames the `_install` script into `install`.

Here's the script field of the package.json found in the husky folder when installed through npm.

```
"scripts": {
    "build": "del-cli lib && tsc",
    "devinstall": "npm run build && npm run _install -- node_modules/husky && node scripts/dev-fix-path",
    "devuninstall": "npm run build && npm run preuninstall -- node_modules/husky",
    "fix": "npm run lint -- --fix",
    "install": "node husky install",
    "lint": "tslint 'src/**/*.ts'",
    "postpublish": "pinst --disable",
    "postversion": "git push && git push --tags",
    "prepublishOnly": "npm run test && npm run build && pinst --enable && pkg-ok",
    "preuninstall": "node husky uninstall",
    "test": "npm run lint && jest",
    "version": "jest -u && git add -A src/installer/__tests__/__snapshots__"
  }
```

Although I can't figure where that is done

Comment: I tried checking their build pipeline but did not find anything, may be I missed something. But I am pretty sure it happens during publish